# Thread has exited with code 0 while calling InstanceID.GetToken

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, firebase, google-cloud-messaging

i have done the "Walkthrough - Using Remote Notifications in Xamarin.Android" step by step as mentiond @ https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/notifications/remote_notifications_in_android/

Till the point "Register with GCM" the project works as it should but with proceeding the of this tutorial, the debugging fails with trying to call the InstanceID.GetToken...

[Output window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XhF4c.png)

The thread ends with code 0...

Has any one an idea how to fix this?
Thanks

Comment: Screenshots of error messages are not the best way to post errors as one cannot copy from them. Please post the error text in your question and also provide a mcve (minimal, complete, verifiable example): http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Thanks for yout input i fixed the problem now using https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/xamarin-notification-hubs-push-notifications-android-gcm/